# How to convert dataframe to csv on AWS Lambda and sendmail with csv attached using SES

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ses

I have to sendmail at the end of my code with csv attached containing a dataframe.

Im doing it at AWS Lambda using boto3 to call SES as it follows.

```
def sendMail1(value, df):
   subject = "Comission"
   client = boto3.client("ses")
   body = f"""
             Comission value is {value}.
           """
message = {"Subject": {"Data": subject}, "Body": {"Html": {"Data": body}}}
attachment = df.to_csv(f"Comission.csv", index=False)
response = client.send_email(Source = "myemail@gmail.com", Destination = {"ToAddresses": ["youremail@gmail.com"]}, Message = message, Attachment = attachment)
```

I had no ideia how to do it, I tried df.to_csv method and include it as attachment. Did not work.

The rest of the code works without the attachment parts, but I need to attach my df to the e-mail.

Do you guys have any idea how to do it?

Comment: How are you connecting to the aws console? Are you using CloudFormation templates/Terraform to set everything up?

Comment: `send_email` doesn't have an attachment param

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv(f"Comission.csv", index=False)

to_emails = [target_email1, target_email2]
ses = boto3.client('ses')
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'weekly report'

msg['From'] = from_email

msg['To'] = to_emails[0]


# what a recipient sees if they don't use an email reader
msg.preamble = 'Multipart message.\n'

# the message body
part = MIMEText('Howdy -- here is the data from last week.')
msg.attach(part)

# the attachment
part = MIMEApplication(open('Comission.csv', 'rb').read())
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='Comission.csv')
msg.attach(part)

result = ses.send_raw_email(
             Source=msg['From'],
             Destinations=to_emails,
             RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()})                                                                                                       
# and send the message
print result
```